# How to remove the comments feed from WP 3.1.1?

Tags: rss

I've tried a number of solutions available on the internet, but none seem to work in WP 3.1.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2); 
add_action('wp_head', 'my_feed_links');

function my_feed_links() {
  if ( !current_theme_supports('automatic-feed-links') ) return;

  // post feed 
  ?>
  <link rel="alternate" type="<?php echo feed_content_type(); ?>" 
        title="<?php printf(__('%1$s %2$s Feed'), get_bloginfo('name'), ' &raquo; '); ?>"
        href="<?php echo get_feed_link(); ?> " />
  <?php 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since WP version 3.0, feed links in the header are expressly enabled with this

```
/**
 * Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
 */
// add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
```

Commenting out this '`add_theme_support`' line (in your `functions.php` file) will remove `/feed/` and `/comments/feed/` links from your header.

Background information here: [Automatic_Feed_Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Automatic_Feed_Links)